# MYSQL showing values greater than 0

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to get data from the `awards_bookings_table` but for some reason I am getting an error with the line below and I am 100% sure its with what I have coded :)

**Goal:**

I would only like to pull the results of table: `awards_booking_tickets` column `ticket_quantity` that are greater then `0`

**Main Join:**

```
`LEFT JOIN `awards_bookings_tickets` bookings_tickets ON bookings.awards_booking_id = bookings_tickets.booking_id`
```

**Issue Code:**

I have tried to do the following:

```
LEFT JOIN `awards_bookings_tickets` bookings_tickets ON bookings.awards_booking_id = bookings_tickets.booking_id WHERE booking_tickets.ticket_quantity > 0
```

Comment: what error text is being generated? can you add it here?

Comment: The code that y ou tried looks syntactically correct, assuming the tables and columns exist.  You need to include the entire SQL statement, since that is probably where the error is.  For instance, you might be trying to join something after the `where` clause, and that would be a problem.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Fixed I had to include AND

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `AND` to combine the clauses, i.e:

```
 INNER JOIN `awards_bookings_tickets` bookings_tickets ON bookings.awards_booking_id = bookings_tickets.booking_id AND booking_tickets.ticket_quantity > 0
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, because it will return rows where there is no match.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `WHERE`?

```
 WHERE booking_tickets.ticket_quantity > 0
```